# maas-import-pxe-files error with md5sum

Tags: maas, cloud, pxe

![I am building a private cloud maas using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have some experience in previous cloud server with the same iso. But now I have got an error in running sudo maas-import-pxe-files. "failled to verify MD5SUMS via /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keying.gpg (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/quantal/main/installer-amd64/current/images//MD5SUMS)". And then command is stopped. what happen? I have no idea to solve. Give me some advice please.]

Comment: I get this problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem was well, as I didn't need quantal images I just edited the /etc/maas/import_pxe_files. I changed the releases line to

```
RELEASES="precise"
```

I ran the command again and it worked